# Is there a way to know when SVG element is resized (eg. resize event)?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a `<div>` with an inline `<svg>` element inside it. When the parent
`<div>` is resized, my `<svg>` drawing is resized, perfect.

My question is:

- is there a way to get notified after the `<svg>` element has been resized?

Indeed, I would like to update some HTML elements I position myself in the
drawing.
I am not using any library, but I don't mind using one if it can solve
my problem.

*EDIT*: I tried the following without success:

```
svg_element.addEventListener("SVGResize", function() { ... });
```

The callback is never called.

Comment: Your question is the same as "is there a way to detect if a div (or any other html element) has been resized?", have you tried searching for that?

Comment: yes, in fact it's very complicated - I solved my problem for now using code from http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/ ; I thought there were something special for svg elements but it doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 0):

Use SVGResize event to detect resize of element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/SVGResize

Comment: Ok, but please tell me how to use it, I already tried without success nothing is fired... I just don't know how to bind the event to my callback.

Comment: The "SVGResize" event has replaced by "resize" in SVG2, also note that it works on the document level, it's not per element.